# OpenStack deployment with MAAS, Juju and Autopilot

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have a problema with my cluster installation. I intend to install OpenStack on my ready set of machines, where each one has 2 NIC and 2 hard disks.

I installed the MAAS controller and Juju on a seventh machine and deployed the landscape scalable bundle. After logging-in into Landscape, it states that the fourth requirement is not fulfilled, because of the lack of a least one machine with two disks and two network interfaces.

MAAS states that I have six machines but the size of disk is of one disk only. I tried to deploy ubuntu on one of them and the second hard disk is present as 'sdb', even though not formatted. MAAS also stats every node has two network interfaces.

What am I doing wrong? I cannot figure out! Should I try to deploy OpenStack with Juju manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Landscape queries MAAS to determine which nodes have multiple network devices. Does MAAS show at least one of the nodes as having two or more MAC addresses *connected to networks* e.g. if you go on the node page, it should say something like 'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF (on maas-eth1)'

If your nodes are on a secondary network which is not MAAS managed, you will have to manually add that network and associate the MAC addresses with it. See the [MAAS docs](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs1.7/networks.html#defining-networks) for help on doing that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I didn't know I had to manually choose the nodes on the network pages. I managed to start the deployment!